# Why do I get CONVERT_IMPLICIT for same data type?

Tags: sql-server

Consider this snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp ( Name varchar(100) )
GO

DECLARE @Name varchar(100)
SELECT  @Name = '123'

SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE Name = @Name
```

When inspecting it's execution plan, I got a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` call on `@Name` variable:

```
[tempdb].[dbo].[#Temp].[Name]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(100),[@Name],0)
```

Why this happens, as I have same data types?

Comment: You're not calling this from .NET or something that would pass in Unicode strings (thus causing nvarchar->varchar conversions)??

Comment: No, I'm running this directly on Management Studio. But I think @MartinSmith got a point

Comment: What if you add `USE tempdb` first? And check server vs db collation too. This would backup @Martin Smith's example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` when running your script in the context of a database with a different collation than `tempdb`.

When running from a DB with the same collation it does not appear in the plan.

In some circumstances this can fail with the error

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed
>   because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation
>   conflict

but I'm not sure of the circumstances when this implicit conversion can't be done.

Comment: There were some changes to collations used in table variables http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179%28SQL.90%29.aspx which is vaguely related to your point here